# Elastic Beanstalk CLI - "a float is required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.5.1 on OSX to deploy a node.js application.

The beanstalk application exists, with no environments.

From my application directory, I run `eb init`.
As prompted, I enter the Access Key ID, the Secret Access Key, choose a region, enter the existing application name, choose a new environment name (`staging`), choose `LoadBalanced` environment type, choose to create an RDS DB Instance, and then it prompts

```
Create an RDS BD Instance from (current value is "[No snapshot]"):
a float is required`
```

And the process exits. (it doesn't allow me to enter a value for the last prompt)

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Are there any alternatives to the `eb` tool?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error when I was trying to deploy a Ruby application to the **64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4**.

Switching to the **64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3** stack resolved the issue and I was able to crate the EB application.